# Sharing files between Ubuntu and Android-x86

Tags: virtualbox, files, transfer

How can I transfer files between Ubuntu and an Android-x86 VirtualBox VM?

Answer (score 1):

Over the network. Maybe it is possible to add a network Adapter in VirtualBox and then download a FileExplorer-App in Android.
In Ubuntu you only have to make a Folder which is accessible over the network.
After that go to the explorer app and add a network share. Now you should be able to transfer files from Android to you host system.

Answer (score 1):

Using [AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/) for Android and your Browser.

> All your files, travel freely between devices, without a cable.

Start AirDroid on your smartphone and open the shown URL in your browser in your virtual machine.

[image]